# React Native: Unable to use `store.dispatch` using redux-saga

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I am using react-native 0.50.3 , I am trying to dispatch a navigation action but I get this error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reducers2.default')

```
import configureStore from '../../../configureStore'

const store = configureStore(); <-- error points here

class childComp extends Component {
    //...
    goToProfile = () => {
       store.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Profile'}));
    }
}
export default childComp;
```

configureStore.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import app from './src/reducers';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootSaga from './sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

export default function configureStore(){
    const store = createStore(app, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)) <-- also error points here
    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
    return store;
}
```

I have already used `store.dispatch` in `index.js` and it works fine.

Reducers

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { TopLevelNavigator } from '../navigation/TopLevelNavigation/TopLevelConfig';
import { MainTabBar } from '../navigation/MainTabBar/MainTabBarConfig';
import { UserFormsTabBar } from '../navigation/UserFormsTabBar/UserFormsTabBarConfig';

import authReducer from './auth';
import employerReducer from './employer';
import contactReducer from './contact';
import personalReducer from './personal';
import bioReducer from './bio';
import saveFormsData from './saveData';
import saveAllFormsData from './saveFormsData';
import peopleReducer from './getPeople';
import currentUserReducer from './getCurrentUser';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    TopLevelNavigationReducer: (state, action) => TopLevelNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state),
    mainTabBarNavigationReducer: (state, action) => MainTabBar.router.getStateForAction(action, state),
    userFormsTabBarNavigationReducer: (state, action) => UserFormsTabBar.router.getStateForAction(action, state),
    authReducer,
    employerReducer,
    contactReducer,
    personalReducer,
    bioReducer,
    saveFormsData,
    saveAllFormsData,
    peopleReducer,
    currentUserReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Are you using `combineReducers` in `./src/reducers`?

Comment: yes, I have already walken away from this use case anyway, asking here and there it turns out that it's not a good practice to use `store` directly. However, when using `redux-thunk` the above just worked fine, but not in saga

Comment: I bet you have a circular dependency. What is being imported in `./src/reducers`?

Comment: @chautelly see update

Comment: Any luck? You excluded the actual import statements from your update so I can't really determine if a circular dependency is the issue here.

Comment: @chautelly see the update. This is not the only issue I have. It behaves weirdly when I dispatch a fetch data from server action from `componentDidMount()` the first time that component loads, no problem, loading shows until data is fetched. but when I navigate back and forth again to the same component. It get stuck at loading (the action is not dispatched again). This problem doesn't appear when I use `redux-thunk`